# Looking for feedback on SQL schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, database-schema

I'm created a database - part of which is below. I'm not an Database or SQL guy so am looking for advice and potential to improve the schema.

The function of the schema is to store Attributes against products. Each product has a ProductType, so Attributes are  constrained via AttributeTypes to specific ProductTypes.

[image]

**Attributes, AttributeTypes and AttributeGroups**
An AttributeType belongs to a single AttributeGroup. An AttributeType can be associated with many Attributes. An Attribute can only have a single AttributeType.

**ProductGroups, ProductTypes and Products**
A ProductType belongs to a single ProductGroup. A ProductType can be associated with many Products. A Product can only have a single ProductType.

**Bridging tables**

ProductTypes_Attributes ensures only valid ProductType_AttributeTypes exist

ProductTypes_AttributeTypes_Products ensures that a Product is correctly mapped to a valid ProductType_AttributeType combination.

```
FK - ProductTypes_AttributeTypes_Products => Products on (ProductID, ProductTypeID)
```

**Product Attributes (3 tables)**
A Product can have many ProductAttributes of the correct type. Product Attributes may be predefined (common) or custom where a description relates uniquely to the Product.

AttributeType is introduced to the ProductCommonAttributes table to ensure integrity between Attributes and ProductAttributes.

```
FK - ProductAttributes => ProductTypes_AttributeTypes_Products (ProductID, AttributeTypeID)

FK - ProductCommonAttributes => ProductAttributes (ProductAttributeID, AttributeTypeID)

FK - ProductCommonAttributes => Attribibutes (AttributeTypeID, AttributeID)
```

Please note there have been some concessions due to the use of an ORM in order to have schema navigate properly.

I look forward to view, comments, advice or questions.

Comment: This type of data model is often called an EAV model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).  Before you to down this path, be aware that queries must often pivot the results and this is cumbersome and error prone,  Even if an ORM does the job for you, the queries will likely be very inefficient compared to those against a 3NF model.

Comment: Cheers for that Dan - these are thie things that noobs find out after the event.

Comment: @DanGuzman - As a matter of interest Dan, which part of the schema are you referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to product, where each product has a different set of attributes.  The performance concerns I mentioned would apply to a use case like an ecommerce site supporting many concurrent users browsing products.  If course, that could/should be mitigated with caching but I'd be more included to take a different approach like the one implemented in the AdventureWorks2014 OLTP Production schema (https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/125550).

Comment: The bottom line is that every product does have a different set of attributes - some of which are repeated in other products, some of which are unique. The easiest approach would probably to just have a list associated text columns stored against each product, which would make lookups super simple - but provide no flexibility. This is not necessarily an issue..

Comment: Good luck analyzing this later when your boss wants a data warehouse